# list files that start with two dots and change file names in bulk

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, centos

I've got file that start with two dots located in different directories.
I need to list them all and change their names in bulk and remove the dots completely.

Any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very efficient, due to the `sh` invocation for each file, but this should work, and is safe:

```
find path -type f -name '..*' -execdir sh -c 'fn=$1; dots=${fn%%[^.]*}; cleaned=${fn:${#dots}}; mv -nv "$fn" "$cleaned"' -- {} \;
```

How it works:

- Find files starting with at least 2 dots.
- Execute a `sh` (with a sequence of commands) in the directory of the file, passing the filename as parameter (`sh -c '...' -- {}`)
- Store the filename in `fn`
- Store the dots prefix in `dots`
- Compute the new filename as a substring of `fn`, starting after the length of `dots`
- Execute `mv`

Comment: Nice. But I'd recommend using `mv -n` or `-i` to avoid accidentally overwriting existing files with the same names.